# Is there a way to trigger an event when a new visit is registered in Google Analytics?

Tags: php, jquery, google-analytics

To my understanding, Google Analytics adds a visit count every time a user does something on the page after 30 minutes of inactivity. Well every time a visit is added, can this trigger an event in jQuery or PHP?

i.e. something like onvisit(do something) or if visit(do something)

Comment: Does it have to be through Google analytics?  You could store a time stamp in a session variable, and if it is older than 30 minutes, or not present, trigger the action.

Comment: Google for "hit callback". You can pass a callback to every interaction method (pageview, event, timing etc.) at least in Universal Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire goggle analytic event when register successfully done. 
You can call this event conditionally in PHP if user successfully registered then call this event.